# Question about the Spectrum of a Bounded Operator in a Hilbert space

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis

I am confused about the below two definitions.
(1) Let $H$ be a Hilbert space over the field $K$ and $T\in B(H)$ be a bounded operator in $H$ the set$$\sigma (T)=\{\lambda \in K:T-\lambda I\text{ is not invertible in }B(H)\},$$which is called the spectrum of $T$. From this definition, we can say that the determinant of $T-\lambda I=0$, it means the set contains all the eigenvalues of the operator.

(2) Let $H$ be a Hilbert space over the field $K$ and $T\in B(H)$ be a bounded operator in $H$ the set$$\sigma _e(T)=\{\lambda \in K:\exists x\in H,\|x\|=1\text{ and }(T-\lambda I)x=0\}.$$From this definition also we can say that the set contains all the eigenvalues,so what is the difference between these two definitions?

Comment: If the dimension of $H$ is infinite  the spectrum may not contain eigenvalues. In  this case you cannot apply determinants. The second set is a subset of the first one.

Comment: Another crucial difference is that, in infinite dimensions, an operator may be injective but fail to be invertible.  If $T-\lambda I$ has these properties, then $\lambda$ lies in the spectrum of $T$ but it is not an eigenvalue!

Answer (score 1):

In finite dimension, they are both the same. In infinite dimension, there is no obvious notion of determinant for an arbitrary operator. Besides, an operator may not have any eigenvalues but still have elements in its spectrum.

The most common example for this is the right unilateral shift and its adjoint the (left) unilateral shift. Let $H=\ell^2(\mathbb N)$ and define
$$
Tx=(x_2,x_3,\ldots),\qquad \qquad Sx=(0,x_1,x_2,\ldots). 
$$
It is easy to show that $\sigma(T)=\overline{\mathbb D}$, the unit disk. It follows that $\sigma(S)=\sigma(T^*)=\overline{\mathbb D}$. Any $z$ with $|z|<1$ is an eigenvalue for $T$ with eigenvector $(z,z^2,z^3,\ldots)$. Meanwhile $S$ has no eigenvalues whatsoever.